# NET Core 3.1 Connection String in appsettings with EntityFramework Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-core

I have a WEB API application and the template (or EF Core) has set me the connection string in the file where the context is located. I want to remove it from there and put it in the appsettings file and read it in the method OnConfiguring() of the DbContext.

```
public partial class ReportingContext : DbContext
{
    public MyAppContext() {}

    public MyAppContext(DbContextOptions<MyAppContext> options) : base(options)  {  }


    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("my-connection-string", x => x.UseNetTopologySuite());
            //I want to remove the connection string from the above line, by reading from the appsettings file
        }
    }

}
```

As you can see it is in the method OnConfiguring of the context. If I try to put outside, in the startup, for example, the application doesn't work anymore as it requires the connection string specified in the OnConfiguring, as the logic in the models instantiates the context in the following way:

```
public partial class SomeClassOfMine
{
    public static List<BusinessLogic.Dto.NearbyMarkets> GetNearbyMarkets(int adm0code, double lat, double lng)
    {
        var geometryFactory = NtsGeometryServices.Instance.CreateGeometryFactory(srid: 4326);
        var location = geometryFactory.CreatePoint(new Coordinate(lng, lat));

        using (var db = new Models.Context.MyAppContext())
        {
          //as you can see above, the context is instantiated without passing parameters, and I don't want to pass the connection string in all the new context instance!
          ...query and logic execution here
        }
     }
}
```

I've tried to use Configuration.GetConnectionString("MyDatabaseDEV"), inside OnConfiguring, but it says that Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration doesn't have a method GetConnectionString

Comment: Did my answer help you solve your problem? If it is solved, please accept it as the answer, otherwise, please tell me your still existing problems.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> how can I inject IConfiguration in the Context class?

To get the connection string in appsetting.json in DbContext, please refer to the writing method:

```
    public class MyDbContext : DbContext
    { 
        public MyDbContext(DbContextOptions<MyDbContext> options)
                : base(options)
        { 
        }
        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
          if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
          {
            IConfigurationRoot configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                          .SetBasePath(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory)
                          .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
                          .Build();
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
           }
         }
    }
```

Please make sure you register the service in `startup.cs`:

```
services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>();
```

appsetting.json:

```
{ 
  //...
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Data Source=(localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB;..."
  }, 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your context probably shouldn't know how it is configured, or even which database engine is being used. In an asp.net core project, that should be the job of your Startup class. For example;

```cs
    public class Startup
    {
        private IConfiguration Configuration;
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDbContextPool<MyDbContext>(o =>
            {
                o.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"), ...);
            });
        }
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host
            .CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            ...
            .ConfigureAppConfiguration((ctx, config) => {
                    config
                        .SetBasePath(ctx.HostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath)
                        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", true, true)
                        .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{ctx.HostingEnvironment.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);
                })
            ... ;
```

The EF Core command line tools will locate your `CreateHostBuilder` method and call it to discover your database context, and how it is configured. For example, when creating migration scripts.